# Revocation check of documents signed before crt was revoked

Tags: java, pdfbox, bouncycastle, pki

I have a pdf document that was signed on the 9 of November with a certificate that was valid at that date, adobe did show the signature as valid, but today that the crt was revoked that document shows that the signature is invalid because the certificate has been revoked. From my understanding this should not happen as it was applied before it was revoked.

The OCSP response has the revocation date so it should be able to verify using that. My code to generate the response is the following:

```
respGen.addResponse(id,
                new RevokedStatus(current_cert.getRevocationDate(),
                current_cert.getReason_num()), nowUpdate,
                nextUpdate);
```

I even tried using a different constructor

```
ASN1GeneralizedTime revocationTime = new ASN1GeneralizedTime(revocationDate);
CRLReason crlReason = CRLReason.lookup(current_cert.getReason_num());
RevokedInfo revokedInfo = new RevokedInfo(revocationTime, crlReason);
respGen.addResponse(id, new RevokedStatus(revokedInfo), nowUpdate, nextUpdate);
```

In theory my code should work, im not sure if adobe has a specific date format and thats why its failing

Comment: What proof do you have that the document was signed *before* the cert expired? Is the document also signed by timestamping authority?

Comment: How is this related to PDFBox?

Comment: Any sensible validation policy nowadays requires not only a *claimed* signing time but a proof thereof (like a time stamp token). Nonetheless, Adobe Reader often is configured to use the claimed, unproven time. But what it needs is revocation information listing the certificate as not revoked. You should have embedded an OCSP response from before the revocation into the pdf.

Comment: @PresidentJamesK.Polk I just have the signing time that adobe shows in the signature properties that says 2021/11/09 and the certificate was revoked on the 2021/11/16 
The document is not being signed by a timestamping authority

Comment: @TilmanHausherr because the error could also be in how i am applying the signature to the document

Comment: @mkl if adobe reader is configured to use the claimed(from my understanding the signing time) shouldn’t it have been valid then? 
Thank you, do you happen to have any guides on how to embed  the ocsp response, as I think I would do it at the moment that the pdf is signed

Comment: If I understand the mechanism involved anybody who has your private key can produce a document that says it was signed on any date, after the fact.

Comment: @PabloArriola *"if adobe reader is configured to use the claimed(from my understanding the signing time) shouldn’t it have been valid then?"* - no. Because the certificate might have been revoked already before the time mentioned in the OCSP response, merely for a different reason. Thus, validation requires an OCSP response (or crl) from a time after (or at most a very short time before) the signing time.

Comment: @PabloArriola *"do you happen to have any guides on how to embed the ocsp response, as I think I would do it at the moment that the pdf is signed"* - there are two different ways to do so, the old ISO 32000-1 compatible way and the PAdES way. Are you required to use one or the other by local laws or convention?

Comment: @PresidentJamesK.Polk *"If I understand the mechanism involved anybody who has your private key can produce a document that says it was signed on any date, after the fact."* - yes. Nonetheless, Adobe Reader accepts the claimed signing time. Actually Adobe Reader used to be way more strict in the early days of pdf signatures but then was confronted with differing validation schemes world wide. To be able to positively validate signatures everywhere, it became less and less strict.

Comment: @mkl but in theory the ocsp response has the date of when the certificate was revoked. So adobe doesnt "trust" that time.
I signed the document five days before and the ocsp response is generated every time I open the pdf. I also tried with a crl that I just generated where it states that the certificate was revoked after the document was signed but it still shows that one of the signatures is not valid because the certificate is revoked. Both of them are generated after the signing time

Comment: @mkl Thank you very much, just to double check, my only way to have the document show as valid signature is to have the embedded ocsp response from after the document was signed that says the certificate is still valid
Even if it makes another ocsp call where it will shows that the certificate is now revoked and that the revocation happened after the signature

Comment: And we don’t  have any special requirement so we are open to suggestions on which  one you think is best or we can even implement both

Comment: @mkl is the claimed signing time a specific property we have to set when generating setting the signature?

Comment: I created an actual answer to your question and tried to include answers to your questions here.

Answer (score 1):

*This answer foremost takes the comments to the question into account.*

#### What Revocation Information Does Adobe Reader Need?

Adobe Reader usually requires revocation information (OCSP responses or CRLs) that state the certificate in question is not revoked.

*In particular it does not suffice to have revocation information stating the certificate has been revoked for some reason at a revocation time after the signing time.*

Such information is needed for all certificates in a certificate chain leading from the signer certificate up to a trusted certificate (exclusively). Furthermore, such information is needed for the signer certificates of those revocation information and their respective chains unless they are marked to not require revocation checks.

*This may sound like a potentially gigantic amount of revocation data. As often CRLs or OCSP responses are signed by the respective CA certificate itself or another certificate issued by it and marked to not require revocation checks, though, there usually only a very few lists or responses are needed.*

All these responses or lists must be generated after the signing time (or at most a very short time before) but before the end of the validity interval of the respectively tested certificate.

#### Which Signing Time is Used For Verification?

What exactly Adobe Reader takes as "signing time" depends on its configuration. On the Signature Verification Preferences dialog you find this frame:

[image: Verification Time frame]

If the first option is selected (like in the image), Adobe accepts the claimed signing time of the signature. This is the time given in the signature dictionary **M** entry or the signing-time attribute of the CMS signature container.

If the second option is selected, Adobe doesn't trust the claimed signing time but accepts the time in a trusted digital timestamp of the signature. (While it only mentions *timestamps embedded in the signature*, it should also accept a *follow-up document timestamp*.)

If the third option is selected, Adobe doesn't trust any given time but always assumes the current time.

#### How Can Good Revocation Information Be Embedded?

There are two interoperable mechanisms to embed validation related information in PDFs:

- **`adbe-revocationInfoArchival` signed attribute**

  Already ISO 32000-1 defines a way to embed validation related information. Here the revocation information is embedded in the CMS signature container itself as a signed attribute:

  > #### 12.8.3.3.2 Revocation Information
  >
  > The adbe Revocation Information attribute:
  >
  > ```
  > adbe-revocationInfoArchival OBJECT IDENTIFIER ::=
  >         { adbe(1.2.840.113583) acrobat(1) security(1) 8 }
  > ```
  >
  > The value of the revocation information attribute can include any of the following data types:
  >
  > - Certificate Revocation Lists (CRLs), described in RFC 3280 (see the Bibliography): CRLs are generally large and therefore should not be embedded in the PKCS#7 object.
  > - Online Certificate Status Protocol (OCSP) Responses, described in RFC 2560, *X.509 Internet Public Key Infrastructure Online Certificate Status Protocol—OCSP* (see the Bibliography): These are generally small and constant in size and should be the data type included in the PKCS#7 object.
  > - Custom revocation information: The format is not prescribed by this specification, other than that it be encoded as an OCTET STRING. The application should be able to determine the type of data contained within the OCTET STRING by looking at the associated OBJECT IDENTIFIER.
  >
  > adbe's Revocation Information attribute value has ASN.1 type RevocationInfoArchival:
  >
  > ```
  > RevocationInfoArchival ::= SEQUENCE {
  >   crl          [0] EXPLICIT SEQUENCE of CRLs, OPTIONAL
  >   ocsp         [1] EXPLICIT SEQUENCE of OCSP Responses, OPTIONAL
  >   otherRevInfo [2] EXPLICIT SEQUENCE of OtherRevInfo, OPTIONAL
  > }
  > OtherRevInfo ::= SEQUENCE {
  >   Type  OBJECT IDENTIFIER
  >   Value OCTET STRING
  > }
  > ```

  *(ISO 32000-1:2008)*

  As this is a *signed* attribute, one has to collect the information already *before* signing. Thus, this mechanism can not be used to add validation related information to an already signed PDF for use with the existing signatures.
- **Digital Security Store (DSS)**

  In the course of profiling different kinds of advanced digital signatures (CAdES, XAdES, PAdES), ETSI specified a structure of PDF objects to hold diverse validation related information which can be added to a signed PDF in an incremental update, i.e. without invalidating the existing signatures.

  You can find the specification of this structure in ETSI EN 319 142-1 which can be freely downloaded, e.g. from [here](https://www.etsi.org/deliver/etsi_en/319100_319199/31914201/01.01.01_60/en_31914201v010101p.pdf):

  > ### 5.4 Validation data and archive validation data attributes
  >
  > #### 5.4.1 Overview
  >
  > Validation of a digital signature requires data to validate the signature such as CA certificates, Certificate Revocation List (CRLs) or certificate status information (OCSP) commonly provided by online services (referred to in the present document as validation data).
  >
  > This clause describes an extension to ISO 32000-1 [1] called Document Security Store (**DSS**) to carry such validation data as necessary to validate a signature, optionally with Validation Related Information (**VRI**) which relates the validation data to a specific signature (see clause 5.4.2). The structure of **DSS** and **VRI** is illustrated in figure 1.
  >
  > [image]

  *(ETSI EN 319 142-1 V1.1.1 (2016-04))*

  The section 5.4.2 specifying this in detail is a bit big for inclusion here, simply download the [norm](https://www.etsi.org/deliver/etsi_en/319100_319199/31914201/01.01.01_60/en_31914201v010101p.pdf).

  This extension to ISO 32000-1 has been integrated into ISO 32000-2, so it's now part of the PDF core.

Which mechanism is better for you, depends on your use case. If the recipients of your signed PDFs use old validation software, you might be better off using the signed attribute approach. If the recipients are in Europe, in particular if they are government agencies there, you should use the **DSS** approach. If you want to extend existing signed PDFs with validation related information, you have to use the **DSS** approach.